# AWS: access private API from public web application

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, load-balancing, node.js, amazon-ecs

I have:

- Private API running on an ECS cluster behind an internal load balancer. This API is used by other services inside the VPC.
- A public Next.js web application.

What I need:

- Give private API access to the Next.js web app. Internet traffic coming from outside this app should not be allowed to access the API.
- Protection from abuse like bots and similar, only real human traffic should be allowed.
- Possibly rate limiting on original client ip.

I was thinking to use a combination of reverse proxy configuration on the Next.js server to proxy api requests to the internal load balancer and some sort of Google recaptcha on the frontend to allow only human requests (but I have some concerns about the recaptcha token 2 minutes duration as stated here https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify).
For the rate limiting requirement maybe an X-Forwarded-For header in the Next.js proxy configuration and an X-Forwarded-For append behaviour on the internal balancer will do the trick? In this way the private API should theoretically be able to extract the original client IP address and do the rate limiting.

What do you think, can this work? Any better idea?